# Accessing dynamically created HiddenField value in Code Behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a `HiddenField` that I'm creating on a GridView's `OnRowDataBound` event:

```
var hF1 = new HiddenField();
e.Row.Cells[10].Controls.Add(hF1);
```

In JavaScript, I'm returning a value from a modal and setting the value on the `HiddenField` for that particular row, "hiddenField" being the ClientID of the `HiddenField`.

```
document.getElementById(hiddenField).value = settings;
```

Now, I have a Button.OnClick event where I need to capture that data for further processing, but I can't determine how I can retreive the data for the specific row.

```
foreach (SPGridViewRow dataRow in gvItems.Rows)
{
    if (dataRow.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow) continue;
    var mySettings = dataRow.... ?
```

How can I capture that value?  Each value in the row's HiddenField control will be unique to that row.  I'm also open to alternative storage of the temporary data held within this field on a per-row basis, just keep in mind that the data is returned from a JavaScript event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating the hidden field in the code behind I would set it up as a template column like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:HiddenField ID="myHiddenFieldID" runat="server" 
             Value='<%# Eval("SomeJSCLientID") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

But that may not be necessary and you may be able to find your hidden control by doing this:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in grid.Rows)
{
   if (((HiddenField)row.FindControl("myHiddenFieldID")).Value)
   {
    //do your thing          
   }            
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark this as the answer although I went with a TextBox in my case.